# How to move a sprite using swipe gesture?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

How can i move a sprite to the left by swiping to the left, move a sprite to the right by swiping to the right and so on?

Like if I swipe to the left, my sprite moves 20 points to the left..I am using SpriteKit and Swift.

Comment: Do you need a fluid animation? Or do you just want the sprite to instantly appear 20 points left/right?

Comment: @jonogilmour Yes, I need to do animated movements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank You! @jonogilmour

I have resolved it in this way:

```
let right = SKAction.moveByX(64, y: 0, duration: 0.6)
    let left = SKAction.moveByX(-64, y: 0, duration: 0.6)
    let up = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 64, duration: 0.6)
    let down = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -64, duration: 0.6)



    func swipedRight(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        player.runAction(right)
    }
    func swipedLeft(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        player.runAction(left)
    }
    func swipedUp(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        player.runAction(up)
    }
    func swipedDown(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        player.runAction(down)
    }


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


        let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedRight:"))
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedLeft:"))
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeUp:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedUp:"))
    swipeUp.direction = .Up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    let swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedDown:"))
    swipeDown.direction = .Down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
............
```

Answer (score 1):

For swipes, you can use `UIGestureRecognizer`, specifically [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html). These are well documented so a simple Google search will give you what you need. Then, you will need to use either `applyForce()` or `applyImpulse()` on your sprite. Again, these are well documented and trivial to implement.

The difference between the two is that an impulse is like hitting a ball with a bat; the impulse is applied once to the object and tapers off over time. A force is applied constantly over time, like a car accelerating. In this case you could apply an impulse on the swipe and be done with it, or you could apply a force and continue applying it whilst `x_distance < 20` in your `update()` method.